# Children of Parent in JFace TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp

How do we retrieve all the children of a selected item in `JFace` `TreeViewer`? I am able to get the parent of a selected item, but not the children.

Answer (score 0):

You normally use the tree content provider to get both the children and the parent of a selection in the tree viewer.

```
IStructuredSelection sel = treeViewer.getStructuredSelection();

Object selElement = sel.getFirstElement();

ITreeContentProvider provider = (ITreeContentProvider)treeViewer.getContentProvider();

Object [] children = provider.getChildren(selElement);

Object parent = provider.getParent(selElement);
```

Note: When using `TreeViewer` you should avoid looking at the `Tree` or `TreeItem` controls that `TreeViewer` uses internally.